# Update same row based on other column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I need the sql for the following scenario.

I am having some set of selected rows.

For example,
Field table, I've filtered the following values

```
Id | yearId
1  | 1 
1  | 2 
1  | 3 
1  | 4 
1  | 5
```

After filtered, i am doing inner join with the existing table,

> Consider Field table having the following columns
>
> Id, yearid, value1, value2, value3,
>   value4,NextYearValue,PreviousYearValue

I need to do inner join with the table and should update like following,

```
value2 = value2 + value1
value3 = value2 + value3
value4 = value3 + value2
NextYearValue = Value2 + value3 + value4
PreviousYearValue = NextYearValue (should be taken from the previous year value)
```

> value3 should get the updated value2 after calculate value2+value1
>
> value4 should get updated value3 and value2 after finish calculation
>   NextYearValue should get all the udpated value.
>
> PreviousYearValue should get the update value from the previous year
>   value (that means previous row in this scenario I think)

Comment: I suspect that what you want is more complex than the example you provided. Could you be more specific?

Comment: Superb.. You guessed correctly.. Wait I'll update

Comment: Updated the question. Please look into that.

Comment: You say value4 is value3+value2, is this correct?

Answer (score 3):

Either set the field the same way as you did with the first value or perform 2 updates.

```
Update @Tbl
set value1=value1+value1,
value2=value1+value1
```

This is basically what you want to do right?

If for some reason you cant do that you could do this:

```
Update @Tbl
set value1=value1+value1

Update @Tbl
set value2=value1
```

Though thats 2 calls so that isn't what i would do

If for some reason this isn't satisfactory maybe you could elaborate on your case? Cause it is kind of strange to have 2 columns with identical values.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with two approaches, I don't know which is faster.

Since your calculations are not complex, you can just do the math:

```
UPDATE FieldTable SET 
value2 = value1 + value2
value3 = value1 + 2*value2 + value3
value4 = 2*value1 + 4*value2 + 2*value3
NextYearValue = 4*value1 + 7*value2 + 3*value3
PreviousYearValue = NextYearValue
```

On a **MySql** approach, you can just use variables:

```
UPDATE FieldTable 
JOIN 
(
  SELECT 
  id,
  @uvalue2 :=value2   + value3   uvalue2,
  @uvalue3 :=@uvalue2 + value3   uvalue3,
  @uvalue4 :=@uvalue2 + @uvalue3 uvalue4,
  @uvalue2 + @uvalue3 + @uvalue4 uNextYearValue,
  NextYearValue uPreviousYearValue
  FROM FieldTable 
) as uFieldTable 
ON FieldTable.id = uFieldTable.id
SET 
value2 = uvalue2,
value3 = uvalue3,
value4 = uvalue4,
NextYearValue = uNextYearValue,
PreviousYearValue = uPreviousYearValue;
```

Considering of course that you have unique ids.

On **Sql Server**, things get more complex, since you probably have to use `Common Table Expressions`

```
WITH FieldTable2 AS(
SELECT id, value2 + value3 value2, value3, value4, NextYearValue FROM FieldTable
) ,FieldTable3 AS(
SELECT id, value2, value3 + value2 value3, value4, NextYearValue FROM FieldTable2
) ,FieldTable4 AS(
SELECT id, value2, value3, value3 + value2 value4, NextYearValue FROM FieldTable3
) ,FieldTable5 AS(
SELECT id, value2, value3, value4, value2 + value3 + value4 NextYearValue FROM FieldTable4
) 
UPDATE FieldTable 
SET 
value2 = FieldTable5.value2,
value3 = FieldTable5.value3,
value4 = FieldTable5.value4,
NextYearValue = FieldTable5.NextYearValue
FROM 
FieldTable5
WHERE FieldTable.id = FieldTable5.id
```

Comment: You have given appropriate answer.. but here previous year value should be taken from the previous year value not with the current row value.. and i forget to add one more line value5 = previousyearvalue + value4

Comment: From second solution, ive got some idea.. Thanks and superb.. Ill check and mark this as answer.

Comment: @JeevaJsb Sadly, my answer is for mySQL, I'll try to fix this and change the answer.

Comment: @JeevaJsb I added the Sql Server query but it is not too elegant. But now I suspect that your problem is not as complex as you present it... Can you briefly explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: I found.. We should take the updated previous year value. When we assign the previous year value, we need to get the updated nextyearvalue from previous row (or year.)

Answer (score 0):

The right hand side of the assignments in an `update` statement are evaluated before being modified by any other assignments in the the same statement. Just apply the same calculation on both expressions and you should be OK:

```
UPDATE @Tbl
SET    value1 = value1 + value1,
       value2 = value1 + value1
```

Comment: This is ok for one or two column. I need to update nearly 7 to 8 column. Is there any alternative and efficient way?

Comment: @JeevaJsb Does the table have a primary key or something?

Answer (score 0):

```
 Update @Tbl
  set value1=value1+value1 
 update @Tbl set value2=value1
```